# cmd command line ^ what does it mean?

Tags: windows, cmd

The function of this command is to input the port to find the corresponding pid, but I don't understand what the ^ symbol is used for, can someone explain it?

```
for /f "tokens=5" %a in ('netstat -aon ^| find ":3306" ^| find  "LISTENING"')  do  echo %a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html

```
Escape Character

  ^  Escape character.

Adding the escape character before a command symbol allows it to be treated as ordinary text. These characters which normally have a special meaning can be escaped and then treated like regular characters  : & \ < > ^ |

e.g. Echo THIS ^& THAT
     Echo Heading1 ^| heading2 ^| heading3
     Echo The Escape character looks like this ^^
```